# How to get User who moved Ticket?

Tags: jira

I'm trying to edit my Jira Workflow to more efficiently track the Developer who developed the ticket.

Right Now, when the Ticket moved to 'Testing' Status, it gets Assigned to the QA on the team. And from there when it moves to 'For Verification' it gets assigned to the PM. When the PM Verifies the ticket, and closes it, it remains assigned to him.

I wanted the ticket to be assigned back to the person who developed this ticket.

In order to do this, I have created a custom field called Developer, and to this field, I want to assign the name of the user who moved the ticket from 'Ready for Dev' to 'In Progress'

How do I Have Jira automatically set the "Developer" field to whomever moves the ticket to "In Progress"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a combination of two Post functions on the 'Started Development' transition which moves from the 'Ready For Dev' to the 'In Progress' status.

1. First you assign the Ticket to the current user (i.e. user who moved the ticket)
2. Then copy the value from the 'Assignee' field to the 'Developer' Field

We need to make sure the order of these two operations is correct.

Once this was done, I added a similar post function to assign the Ticket back to the developer, by copying the value from the Developer field, to the Assignee field on Verification.